# Error inflating class com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-layout, inflate-exception

Hi guys can you help me how to fix this problem, i dont know why the problem is actionbar, i try to import this project from eclipse, and so hard to fix so many all of the project trouble, I try to remove the library v4 support but it's not work

problem `android.view.InflateException`

Short code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.depan);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
            LoginActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String userName = settings.getString("user_name", "");
    TextView vw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    vw.setText(userName);
    TextView tvcopyright = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.depan_copyright);
    tvcopyright.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    targetUrl = Config.getEndPointUrl();
    ctx = this.getApplicationContext();

    final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    // actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, createIntent(this),
    // R.drawable.ic_title_home_demo));
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    LinearLayout lyUpdate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutUpdate);
    if (!AppInfo.needupdate) {
        lyUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateApp);
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String url = targetUrl + "/getapp.json?userid="
                            + UserInfo.username;
                    // url =
                    // "http://10.0.2.2/nestleconfect/data/user/NestleConfectMobile.apk";
                    // String type =
                    // "application/vnd.android.package-archive";

                    Log.i("ncdebug", "update: " + url);

                    Update(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void Update(String apkurl) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(apkurl);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();

                    String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/download/";
                    File file = new File(PATH);
                    file.mkdirs();

                    File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();

                    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    promptInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/download/app.apk")),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    startActivity(promptInstall);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Update error! " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // db update
    LinearLayout lyDbUpdate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutDbUpdate);
    if (!AppInfo.dbNeedUpdate) {
        lyDbUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        Button btnDbUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDbUpdateApp);
        btnDbUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, DbUpdateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PeriodicTaskService.class);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.message_btn);
    AppInfo.contextmain = ctx;
    AppInfo.messagebtn = view;
    startService(intent);

    String currentDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d")
            .format(new Date());
    AppInfo.date = currentDateString;

    Log.i("ncdebug", "userid(main): " + UserInfo.username + ",name="
            + UserInfo.name);
}
```

Here is my layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        style="@style/ActionBar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayoutUpdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="30dip"
        android:paddingRight="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdateApp"
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Update Ke Versi Terbaru"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the log :

```
    stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                     at com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                     at com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                     at com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/markupartist/android/widget/actionbar/R$layout;
                                                                     at com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.<init>(ActionBar.java:57)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                     at com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53) 
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.markupartist.android.widget.actionbar.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.2.0_172ab3f548c6de548a79bebb7324b06edd4ccef2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md/files/instant-run/dex/slice-maps_b9
08-25 06:14:39.749 9239-9239/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 61712
08-25 06:19:39.756 9239-9239/com.inarts.mobile.merch.md I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9239 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please paste the error log as well - this might shed more light on what might be the issue.

Comment: Also check your Theme, probably you are using AppCompatTheme that needs support library v7 that needs support library v4. I don't think that today is possible to build a project without support library v4 and v7.

Comment: if you are using eclipse than do Import support library as a project from "sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat". and studio than import the dependecies

Comment: In your theme, have you specified action bar to be removed?

Comment: i dont remove it @Shaishav, whether the external actionbar library and google new  actionbar is clashed ?

Comment: @LWiraSatriaM  Yeah...I'd try removing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How and/or where are you getting the definition of "com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar"?

That doesn't look like a standard widget, and since the project builds for you and crashes on run, my guess is that it's not being included and deployed with your project.

Try briefly switching back to the standard ActionBar, verify that it works like that, then jump back to the custom ActionBar widget that you're using.

Adding the ADB log might help too.

Comment: "com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar" try to look at the xml on my post, i use it there, if i change with the standar actionbar appcompat cause the problem with some other method on some activity

Comment: I think you missed my shorthand.  The 'com.markupartist.android.widget.Actionbar' in XML is a reference to an actual Java class that implements the view.  If you have it available at compile time, you won't get an error during your build.  If it doesn't get deployed with your APK, you'll get a runtime inflate error when it comes time to actually use it.